# Need help with SQL Server PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I know about the PIVOT feature in SQL Server and I've read a few other questions and answers on here but I just can't seem to grasp it in order to do what I need. I'm trying to run some calculations and I have the following:

```
TABLE office_settings
column office_id (bigint not null)
column setting_value (NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL)

office_id    setting_value
--------------------------------------------
4             0.2
4             0.2
4             2
4             3
5             0.2
5             0.2
5             2
5             3
```

I'd like to convert this using PIVOT (assuming that's the right tool for the job) to this, basically "grouping by" the office_id column, so:

```
office_id    value_1    value_2    value_3   value_4
------------------------------------------------------
    4         0.2         0.2         2         3
    5         0.2         0.2         2         3
```

I should also mention that I need to CAST the setting_value column values to DECIMAL(4,2) in the process of this - in case that has any bearing on the T-SQL required to accomplish it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select office_id,
[1] as value_1, [2] as value_2, 
[3] as value_3, [4] as value_4
from
(
  select office_id, setting_value,
    row_number() over(partition by office_id order by office_id) rnk
  from office_settings
) d
pivot
(
  max(setting_value)
  for rnk in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

Or without using `PIVOT` (generates the same execution plan):

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT 
        OS.office_id,
        OS.setting_value,
        row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            -- Note: non-deterministic
            PARTITION BY OS.office_id 
            ORDER BY OS.office_id)
    FROM dbo.office_settings AS OS
)
SELECT
    N.office_id,
    value_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN N.row_num = 1 THEN N.setting_value ELSE NULL END),
    value_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN N.row_num = 2 THEN N.setting_value ELSE NULL END),
    value_3 = MAX(CASE WHEN N.row_num = 3 THEN N.setting_value ELSE NULL END),
    value_4 = MAX(CASE WHEN N.row_num = 4 THEN N.setting_value ELSE NULL END)
FROM Numbered AS N
GROUP BY
    N.office_id;
```

With dynamic sql (useful when number of pivot columns varies within a search window):

```
declare @pivcols as varchar(200);

select  @pivcols = stuff((select distinct '],[' + cast(row_number() 
over(partition by office_id order by office_id) as varchar(10))
from office_settings
for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + ']';

declare @pivquery varchar(500); 

set @pivquery = 'Select office_id, '+   
@pivcols +' 
from   
(select office_id, setting_value, 
 row_number() over(partition by office_id order by office_id) rnk
 from office_settings
) as d
PIVOT
(
max(setting_value)
for rnk in ( '+ @pivcols +' )
) AS pvt ';


EXECUTE(@pivquery);
```