# Pivot applications per student

Tags: sql-server, query, pivot

I have two tables:

1. STUDENTS
2. APPLICATION

A student can apply to 1-3 programs. `Student_ID` is a column on Application.

#### Table structure

```
APPLICATION 
ID  | Student_ID   | ProgramName
1   |     65432    |  ComputerScience
2   |     65432    |  Math
3   |     65432    |  Cinema
4   |     65431    |  Theatre
5   |     65431    |  Cinema  
etc...
```

The end goal is to get to this:

1 student per row, with all their application programs

#### Expected results

```
First     | Last     | Program1        |  Program2 | Program3
Robert    | De Niro  | ComputerScience |  Math     | Cinema
Sponge    | Bob      | Theatre         |  Cinema   |
```

#### Questions

1. Can this be achieved with one SQL statement?

   What would it be?
   If not, what would be the approach (and queries) to use an intermediate table?
2. If we're not sure each student has exactly 3 applications, (can have one or two) - does this change anything?

---

I am using SQL Query Activity on Salesforce Marketing Cloud. The documentation says:

> SQL support for the SQL Query Activity is based on, but does not precisely correspond to, SQL Server 2005 capabilities.

Looked into `PIVOT`. I found that it is used with aggregation operators (`AVG`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, etc.) - which is not the case here.

Comment: The general solution is in the [linked duplicate Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63698/need-help-with-sql-server-pivot). Translated for your data one example solution is https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=aae6cf0637ba14106622edbb7a01d6bd

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that ! Thanks Paul